# Oracle SQL query rows to columns

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot

[image: table]

i have the above data in a table and what im trying to achieve is the following

**DESIRED RESULT**

```
ITMCOD    BUOMNUM     BUOMDEN   BUOMNUM_CS
80240277  10000        4444        200
```

Sorry im not able to format this as a table for some reason. MNy current sql is only able to return the results shown in the image.

Im only interested in the rows where UOM is CS or SU, but then the BUOMNUM field contains two entries which i need to have in separate columns. One for where UOM is CS and the other for where UOM is SU.

Whats the sql code to do this please? My colleague suggested a PIVOT function but i cant get that to work. Im using Oracle 11g.

cheers

EDIT:

Here is my SQL that produces the list of products that im trying to query further to produce the desired result shown above:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   ( 
              SELECT     m.itmcod, 
                         m.itmgrp, 
                         m.itmdsc, 
                         u.buomden, 
                         u.buomnum, 
                         u.uom AS unit 
              FROM       itmmst m 
              inner join item_uom u 
              ON         m.itmcod = u.itmcod 
              WHERE      u.uom IN ('CS','SU') 
    ) 
        PIVOT (count(unit) FOR unit IN ('CS' cs,'SU' su) )
```

This code works, what im struggling with is separating the CS and SU to separate columns as explained above.

cheers

Comment: Why does the PIVOT function not work? What have you tried and can you provide the PIVOT code?

Comment: hi, Sorry the pivot function works and have edited the question to include it. Im now trying to include Francisco's code below to make mine a sub query of it but having issues with the max statements

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this. It works fine if you have only one row containing SU and one containing CS for each ITMCOD value. If you have more, then we'd need criteria to choose which CS and which SU you want to display.
In the example below I assumed you want to see BUOMDEN from the SU row.

```
SQL> with t as (
  2  select 80240277 itmcod, 'CS' uom, 200 buomnum, 1 buomden from dual union all
  3  select 80240277 itmcod, 'GU' uom, 1 buomnum, 8 buomden from dual union all
  4  select 80240277 itmcod, 'IT' uom, 1 buomnum, 1 buomden from dual union all
  5  select 80240277 itmcod, 'SP' uom, 1 buomnum, 1 buomden from dual union all
  6  select 80240277 itmcod, 'SU' uom, 10000 buomnum, 4444 buomden from dual union all
  7  select 80240277 itmcod, 'SW' uom, 10 buomnum, 1 buomden from dual
  8  ) -- end of sample test data
  9  select itmcod,
 10         max(case when uom = 'SU' then buomnum end) buomnum,
 11         max(case when uom = 'SU' then buomden end) buomden,
 12         max(case when uom = 'CS' then buomnum end) buomnum_cs
 13    from t
 14   where uom in ('CS', 'SU')
 15   group by itmcod;
    ITMCOD    BUOMNUM    BUOMDEN BUOMNUM_CS
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
  80240277      10000       4444        200
```

Answer (score 0):

i used this method in the end which avoided the pivot all together

```
select x.itmcod,x.itmdsc,
MAX(DECODE(x.unit,'SU',x.buomden)) BuomDEN_SU,
MAX(DECODE(x.unit,'SU',x.buomnum)) BuomNUM_SU,
MAX(DECODE(x.unit,'CS',x.buomnum)) Buomnum_CS,
COALESCE(((MAX(DECODE(x.unit,'SU',x.buomden))/MAX(DECODE(x.unit,'SU',x.buomnum))  )* MAX(DECODE(x.unit,'CS',x.buomnum))),0) CALCULATED_SU
from (
              SELECT     m.itmcod, 
                         m.itmgrp, 
                         m.itmdsc, 
                         u.buomden, 
                         u.buomnum, 
                         u.uom AS unit 
              FROM       itmmst m 
              inner join item_uom u 
              ON         m.itmcod = u.itmcod 
              WHERE      u.uom IN ('CS','SU') 
  ) x
  group by x.itmcod,x.itmdsc
```